# How to translate Java's inner anonymous classes into Nativescript JS?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How do I translate the following Java code into Nativescript JS?

Assuming the all the libraries/namespaces are already in place, only syntax needed

```
mMapView.addViewpointChangedListener(new ViewpointChangedListener() {
  @Override public void viewpointChanged(ViewpointChangedEvent viewpointChangedEvent) {
    // do thing
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have implement the `ViewpointChangedListener` interface and then pass the instance of same to `addViewpointChangedListener` method. Similar to how `OnClickListener` interface is implemented [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin-custom#platform-specific-code).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here in the docs : https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces

So, in the end it turns this way :

```
this.mapView.addViewpointChangedListener(new com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.ViewpointChangedListener({
    viewpointChanged: (args) => {
        //do thing
    }
}));
```